# I'm trying to share a file from my android app, but iIm getting an error like file not supported or unknown file

Tags: android, file, path, sharing

I'm trying to share a file from my android app, but I'm getting an error like file not supported or unknown file.

```
CommonMethods commonMethods = new CommonMethods();
String internalFile = commonMethods.getDate();
String sharepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/My Records/" + internalFile + "/";
Uri urii = Uri.parse(sharepath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,urii);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share Sound File"));
```

Comment: Have you added these two permissions in the `AndroidManifest` file?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Your `Uri` is invalid, as it lacks a scheme. Even if you used `Uri.fromFile()` to get a `Uri` with a `file` scheme, that `Uri` will give you a `FileUriExposedException`. Please use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` suitable for sharing.